# LOAD DATA INFILE not working inside BASH SCRIPT

Tags: mysql, csv, ssh, load

I am new to ssh ,trying to laod csv files through bash script using LOAD DATA INFILE syntax using bash script

Here is my script:

```
mysql -u $MYSQL_USERNAME -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -D $MYSQL_DATABASE \
  load data local infile '$FILE_TR_HI' into table trans_hist_test \
  fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\r\n';
```

This script runs fine individually. I mean outside the script.
But when I include this in script, it throws an error

> Load command not found

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide a full path to mysql

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u ...
```

Comment: No it didn't work. I gave the path in my case the path was /usr/share/MySQL -u ..  but it throws me a error again "/usr/share/MySQL" is a directory and "load:command not found"

Comment: @user2376510 you should locate the mysql executable path , "/usr/share/MySQL" this points to a directory so see if it contains a "bin"  directory and inside the mysql executable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the --execute option of mysql using -e.

---

```
mysql -u $MYSQL_USERNAME -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -D $MYSQL_DATABASE -e "load data local infile '$FILE_TR_HI' into table trans_hist_test fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\r\n'"
```

Comment: it didn't work !! I got this error mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.69, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion,

Comment: It works for me and it should work. Can u check if you have permission for "LOAD DATA"?